# Hot water stops running intermittently

Tags: hot-water

When I run the hot water to the bathroom sink, as soon as the water starts to heat up, the tap just stops, and I have to give the top bit a few more turns to get it flowing again. It will then usually stop a couple more times, and I find I have to switch it off then back on again to get it flowing again. Happens every time, but only this tap - the bath tub and the shower, both in the same room, are fine.

I've got a fairly new combi boiler (3 yrs), which is maybe 3 or 4 meters from the problem tap (in another room). The pipes going to the basin are a little wobbly, I'm thinking about zip tying them together to make them more stable.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me. The rubber washer fell off the bib screw and blocked the valve when it heated and expanded.

Take it apart and take a look.

Comment: is this in the tap, or the boiler?

Comment: It was in the tap.

Answer (score 0):

If its the lime deposits expanding with the heat, you might want to try backflushing as described here: http://www.thesuperhandyman.com/?page_id=158
However, take the aerator off the good faucet before starting so that any loose sediment doesn't plug it.